# How to get sentiment tag using word2vec

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I'm working on word2vec model in order to analysis a corpus of newspaper.
I have a csv which contains some newspaper like tital, journal, and the content of the article.
I know how to train my model in order to get most similar words and their context.

However, I want to do a sentiment analysis on that. I found some ressources in order to do that but in all the test or train dataframe in the examples, there is already a column sentiment (0 or 1). Do you if it's possible to classify automaticaly texts by sentiment ? I mean put 0 or 1 to each text. I search but i don't find any references about that in the word2vec or doc2vec documentation...

Thanks for advance !

Answer (score 1):

Both `Word2Vec` & `Doc2Vec` are just ways to turn words or lists-of-words into 'dense' vectors. Alone, they won't tell you sentiment.

When you have a text and want to deduce which categories it belongs to, that's called 'text classification'. Specifically, if you have just two categories (like 'positive-sentiment' vs 'negative-sentiment', or 'spam' vs 'not-spam'), that's called 'binary classification'.

The output of a `Word2Vec` or `Doc2Vec` model might be helpful in that task, but mainly as input to some other chosen 'classifier' algorithm. And, such algorithms require some 'labeled examples' of each kind of text - where you supply the *right* answer – in order to work. So, you will likely have to go through your corpus of newspaper articles & mark a bunch of them with the answer you want.

You should start by working through some examples that use `scikit-learn`, the most popular Python library with text-classification tools, even *without* any `Word2Vec` or `Doc2Vec` features, at first. For example, in its docs is an intro:

"[Working With Text Data](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html)"

Only after you've set up some basic code using generic preprocess/feature-extraction/training/evaluation steps, and reviewed some actual results, should you then consider if adding some features based on `Word2Vec` or `Doc2Vec` might help.